# Missing characters when exporting to pdf from indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I'm getting a random error when exporting a indd file to pdf.

I'm on OS X 10.9.5 and running indesign and acrobat pro CS4.
The font in question is helvetica neue light (true type).

The indesign preview looks fine.
[image: Indesign font preview]

However the pdf looks like this:
[image: PDF exported from indesign]

I've tried several methods to try and resolve the problem

1. Checked font file in Font Book - all was fine.
2. Checked several pdf export profiles
3. Turned on/off ligatures - turning off ligatures made all characters appear missing
4. Checked several pdf preflight font profile checks

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The PDF appears to be a different font face. Check the PDF file > properties > fonts tab for any info regarding font embedding. In Ye Olde Days, mixing Type1 and TTF fonts sometimes meant "undefined behavior."

Comment: see also: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1547833

Comment: You could also be using a font which doesn't allow to be exported into a PDF because of embedding restrictions. If that is the case you could contact the font developer, modify the font if you have the rights to do so, or simply create outlines in InDesign whenever this font appears.

Comment: Are you using the system font "Helvetica Neue" that comes with Apple OSX? That version is 'enhanced' by Apple, and is no longer a perfectly normal regular font. It has been reported that Adobe's software has problems with it. Try changing your document to use a normally installed Helvetica Neue Std.

Comment: It may actually be a conflict between the system font and a second version. The fonts are *very* similar, but barring a mere rendering difference the 3, 6, and g (especially) are "flattened vertically" in specimen one as compared to specimen 2.